# Authorize.net Accept Hosted Customer Profile Page has no button to return

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net

I am using the Authorize.net Accept Hosted "Get Hosted Profile Page" action using *redirect* instead of *iframe*.  Everything is working so far, redirect is happening, token is getting passed . . . but there is literally no button to proceed and/or go back to my site after the customer is redirected to this page (?).  Am I missing something?  I am passing a redirect URL in to get my token, so I'd expect there to be something happening.

I'm using the .NET SDK on my backend.

```
string token = null;

var settings = new settingType[]
{
    new settingType
    {
        settingName = settingNameEnum.hostedProfileReturnUrl.ToString(),
        settingValue = model.ReturnUrl.AbsoluteUri
        // ^^^ here's why my redirect url goes
    }
};

var profileReq = new getHostedProfilePageRequest();
profileReq.customerProfileId = model.CustomerProfileId;
profileReq.hostedProfileSettings = settings;

var controller = new getHostedProfilePageController(profileReq);
controller.Execute();

var resp = controller.GetApiResponse();
// ^^^ this all works fine, token is returned
```

Here's the page to which I'm redirected at https://test.authorize.net/customer/manage (the sandbox), below.  There's no button to advance or go backwards.  I've tried clicking everywhere.

[image: Redirected Page]

How do I get back to my site?

Comment: hmm.. try adding another `settingType`.. perhaps `hostedProfileReturnUrlText` setting.  in ref to [settingNameEnum - github](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet/blob/705b310101bda56281e1e03a5bf41d73eb72b71b/Authorize.NET/Utility/AnetApiSchema.generated.cs#L5119)

Comment: Thanks @BrettCaswell. I tried adding that too, but there is still no button coming up.  The `ReturnUrlText` is supposed to default to a value as well, but even if I override it . . . nada

Comment: I mean the setting descriptions on that setting indicate there is supposed to be a "Continue" button (when finishing up, whatever that entails), ref [Guidelines_for_Parameter_Settings - developer.authorize.net/api/reference](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html#Guidelines_for_Parameter_Settings)

This may be a product support question at this point. a user feature or usability issue in that respect.